# can we add purchased fonts to google font api?

Tags: fonts

can we add purchased fonts to google font api?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you cannot upload arbitrary font files from your own sources.

You can load other fonts via the [Web Font Loader](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.html), from sources other than Google (e.g. [TypeKit](http://typekit.com/) or [Fonts Live](http://www.fontslive.com/) - but that might be violating the terms of use of the purchased font.